# templates and overload resolution

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor

I'm reading the book "C++ templates, complete guide", and on chapter 22 it introduces the concept of type erasure with an example of a std::function-linke class:

```
#include "functorwrapper.hpp"

// primary template (declaration)
template <typename Signature>
class Function;

// partial class template specialization
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
class Function<ReturnType(Args...)>
{
public:
    // constructors
    Function() : mFunctorWrapper(nullptr) {}                 // default constructor
    Function(const Function &);                              // copy constructor
    Function(Function &&);                                   // move constructor
    template <typename Functor> Function(Functor &&);        // generalized constructor

    // destructor
    ~Function() { delete mFunctorWrapper; }

    // copy/move operations
    Function &operator=(Function const &);                          // copy assignmaent operator
    Function &operator=(Function &&);                               // move assignment operator 
    template <typename Functor> Function &operator=(Functor &&);    // generalized assignment operator

    // overloaded function call operator
    ReturnType operator()(Args...);
private:
    FunctorWrapperBase<ReturnType(Args...)> *mFunctorWrapper;
};

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
Function<ReturnType(Args...)>::Function(const Function &other) : mFunctorWrapper(nullptr)
{
    if (other.mFunctorWrapper)
        mFunctorWrapper = other.mFunctorWrapper->Clone();
}

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
Function<ReturnType(Args...)>::Function(Function &&other) :  mFunctorWrapper(other.mFunctorWrapper)
{
    other.mFunctorWrapper = nullptr;
}

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
template <typename Functor>
Function<ReturnType(Args...)>::Function(Functor &&functor)
{
    // remove reference if l-value (template type argument deduced as Functor &)
    mFunctorWrapper = new FunctorWrapper<typename std::remove_reference<Functor>::type, ReturnType(Args...)>(std::forward<Functor>(functor));
}

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
Function<ReturnType(Args...)> &Function<ReturnType(Args...)>::operator=(const Function &other)
{
    mFunctorWrapper = other.mFunctorWrapper->Clone();

    return *this;
}

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
Function<ReturnType(Args...)> &Function<ReturnType(Args...)>::operator=(Function &&other)
{
    mFunctorWrapper = other.mFunctorWrapper;
    other.mFunctorWrapper = nullptr;

    return *this;
}

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
template <typename Functor>
Function<ReturnType(Args...)> &Function<ReturnType(Args...)>::operator=(Functor &&functor)
{
    mFunctorWrapper = new FunctorWrapper<typename std::remove_reference<Functor>::type, ReturnType(Args...)>(std::forward<Functor>(functor));
}

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
ReturnType Function<ReturnType(Args...)>::operator()(Args... args)
{
    mFunctorWrapper->Invoke(args...);
}
```

this class just manages the memory allocated for an object of type FunctorWrapper, which is a class template that represents different kinds of functors (or callables).

If I construct an object of type Function from a function object, a lambda or a pointer to a function it all goes well (I can call the object and the relative function is called).

But if I try to copy construct (or move construct) a Function from another Function, the compiler binds the call only to the constructor that takes an arbitrary object (the generalized constructor with template parameter Functor and an universal reference as function parameter), causing a crash.

I thought that if I call the constructor like:

```
Function<void(double)> fp4(&FreeFunction);
fp4(1.2);

Function<void(double)> fp5 = fp4;  // copy construction
```

the copy constructor should be called, since it's more specialized.
I followed the example on the book, but I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Why do you think copy constructor should be called in this case `fp5 = fp4` ? Copy ctor has `const` in its signature. But `fp4` is non-const object. So overload with perfect forwarding has better match than `F(const F&)` and it is used in this case. When you change `fp4` to be const object, then copy ctor will be called. Because when compiler has two overloads with the same match - one as normal function, and another templated version, normal function is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a defect in the book.

> the copy constructor should be called, since it's more specialized

`template <typename Functor> Function(Functor &&);` is a better match.

After `typename Functor` is deduced as `Function<...> &`, the constructor turns into `Function(Function &);`, which is a better match than `Function(const Function &);` if you pass a non-const object to it.

You can fix this with SFINAE:

```
template
<
    typename Functor,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<Function,
        std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<Functor>>>>
>
Function(Functor &&);
```

You need to do the same thing with the assignment operator. Alternatively, you could simply remove it (assigning a functor should still work, as the compiler should call `Function(Functor &&)` followed by the move assignment).

Comment: Actually it's a defect in my implementation. The book explicitly defines a Function(Function &other) that delegates to Function(Function const &other) after casting the parameter to const Function &.   Now it works as it should

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unfortunately the forwarding reference version is a better match than the copy constructor, which requires an implicit conversion to the reference to **const**.

You can put constraints as

```
template <typename Functor, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<Function, std::decay_t<Functor>>>* = nullptr> 
Function(Functor &&);
```

<sub>PS: I used `std::is_base_of` instead of `std::is_same`, for the case that `Function` might be inherited, and in the implementation of copy constructor of the derived class, the copy constructor of `Function` might be invoked with an argument with the derived class type.</sub>